# Convert a char to upper case

Tags: rust

I have a variable which contains a single `char`. I want to convert this `char` to upper case. However, the `to_uppercase` function returns a `rustc_unicode::char::ToUppercase` struct instead of a `char`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ToUppercase` is an iterator, because the uppercase version of the character may be composed of several codepoints, as delnan pointed in the comments. You can convert that to a Vector of characters:

```
c.to_uppercase().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Then, you should collect those characters into a string, as ker pointed.

Comment: And then you only have to take the first char of the vector : https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cd2f82bd96c6ffa26ef1&version=stable  Isn't this very bloated for such a trivial thing to do ?

Comment: No, my answer is wrong. Please read the comments. That will work in some cases, but is incorrect on the general case.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I can't answer the question myself. I haven't deleted the answer yet because comments contain valid information. Should I delete it?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt:  Just did. Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

#### Explanation

`ToUppercase` is an `Iterator`, that may yield more than one `char`. This is necessary, because some Unicode characters consist of multiple "Unicode Scalar Values" (which a Rust `char` represents).

A nice example are the so called [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). Try this for example ([on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=618d0ddf2ccb9f6f50756a3b9713d4b1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
let fi_upper: Vec<_> = 'ﬁ'.to_uppercase().collect();
println!("{:?}", fi_upper);   // prints: ['F', 'I']
```

The 'ﬁ' ligature is a single character whose uppercase version consists of two letters/characters.

---

#### Solution

There are multiple possibilities how to deal with that:

1. **Work on `&str`**: if your data is actually in string form, use [`str::to_uppercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_uppercase) which returns a `String` which is easier to work with.
2. **Use ASCII methods**: if you are sure that your data is ASCII only and/or you don't care about unicode symbols you can use [`std::ascii::AsciiExt::to_ascii_uppercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/trait.AsciiExt.html#tymethod.to_ascii_uppercase) which returns just a `char`. But it only changes the letters `'a'` to `'z'` and ignores all other characters!
3. **Deal with it manually**: Collect into a `String` or `Vec` like in the example above.